# php redirect form and url's

Tags: php, forms

I'v created a form , if the user does not fill in all the fields , the aim is to refresh the page the current page. The problem is with line number seven.

One the page is refreshed and the url changes. The code adds %20 into the URL. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Once the form is sumbmited , i also want to redirect the user to a 'thankyou page' to prevent them resubmitting the form several times using the refresh button or browser back button. Is this possible and the most secure way ? The header() function does not seem to work

Many thanks , I really appreciate peoples efforts

```
    <h2>post a comment</h2>

     <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">


    <table width "600" bgcolor="99CCCC">


        <tr>
            <td>Your Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment_name"/></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Your email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment_email"/></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Your Comment:</td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" cols="35" rows="16"/></textarea></td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="postcom"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 


 <?php                               


    $errors = [];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'] )) {

     // php scheck if comment is set 

    $comment_name = $_POST['comment_name'];
    $comment_email = $_POST['comment_email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $status ="unapprove";  // This is a variable called status

   if($comment_name=='' OR $comment_email=='' OR $comment=='') {   

   $errors[] = 'field is empty!';

  // echo "<script>window.open('post_details.php?post=$post_id')</script>";

    } else {


   header('Location: www.google.com');
    exit; // prevents rest of code execute

    }

}

 if(count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
         echo $error . '<br>';
    }
 }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
<?php 

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $foobar = $_POST['foobar'];

    if(empty($foobar)) {
        $errors[] = 'Foobar field is empty!';
    } else {
        // Do some stuff
        header('Location: thankyoupage.php');
        exit;
    }

}

if(count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . '<br>';
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="foobar">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You should always call `exit` construct after `header()` calls to prevent further script execution.
Also, `%20` is a code for space. Don't use spaces in your url if you want to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks META but the header function still doesn't seem to be working. any ideas? i've edited the original post to show the changes that i have implemented

Comment: @user2324730 What do you see when you submit the form with filled fields? The redirect is working for me.

Comment: Thanks, the form is on the following page:

http://localhost:8888/mycms/post_details.php?post=78


when i fill out the form and press sumbit, the form blanks out and sends me to 


http://localhost:8888/mycms/post_details.php
 (no post id at the end of url)

Comment: @user2324730 Is your script aware of post id to redirect to? Try `header('Location: mypage.php?post=' . $post_id);`.